# Linked Image Syntax for Mediawiki

Tags: syntax, mediawiki

I tried to add a linked image to a wiki page without luck. The HTML syntax for the linked image is below:

```
<a href="External Link" class="fancybox-iframe {width:800,height:600}"><img width="300" height="220" alt="Virtual Tour" src="Path to Image" title="Virtual Tour" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-8517"></a>
```

What's the right syntax for linked image in MediaWiki?

I am using **[[File:Fielname.jpg|frame|||||link=External Link|alt=ALT|Caption]]**

But I need to add CSS class to both A and IMG tag and it seems I cannot.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that syntax is correct. And yes, you can't add any attributes to anchor or image tags. Why would you need to?

Comment: Thanks. It is because this wiki page will be reused: it will be embed in different pages. If I am able to put linked image with class in wiki, then it can save my time and make maintenance easier.

Comment: How are you embedding it? What are the classes used for?

Comment: It is embedded in Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Create a template once **Template:MyReusedImage** with your image in right size, title etc.
Then reuse the template on the pages {{MyReusedImage}}